# SQL in Java; Error dealing with SELECT and GROUP BY

Tags: mysql

For starters, I'm a super novice in SQL, and so I don't have the knowledge to ask a straightforward question, but I'll do my best.  Here is the query I'm trying to make:

```
query = conn1.prepareStatement(
"select Industry, Ticker, TransDate, min(TransDate), max(TransDate), " +
"     count(distinct TransDate) as TradingDays, " +
"     count(distinct Ticker) as TickerCnt, " +
"     openPrice, closePrice " +
"  from  Company left outer join PriceVolume using(Ticker) " +
"  group by Industry " +
"  having TradingDays >= 150 " +
"  order by Industry, Ticker, TransDate");
ResultSet rs = query.executeQuery();
```

Here's the Error:
`SQLException: Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'reedy330.Company.Ticker' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`

If I include Ticker and TransDate in the GROUP BY clause, the exception no longer happens, but the `ResultSet` is empty. What I'm trying to do is have a `ResultSet` with everything in the `SELECT` clause as elements. I built this query from a similar example query in the assignment description, which is why I don't understand it well.

Here is the layout of the database, table names bolded with a colon, keys are just in bold:

> **PriceVolume:**
>   **Ticker**
>   **TransDate**
>   OpenPrice
>   HighPrice
>   LowPrice
>   ClosePrice
>   Volume
>   AdjustedGross
>
> **Company:**
>   **Ticker**
>   Name
>   Industry
>   Location

Any ideas?

Comment: Ideas on what? As I heard on SO once: This is a story, what is your question?  Welcome to Stack Overflow!  This is not meant to discourage, but encourage being explicit.

Answer (score 0):

Is "sql_mode=only_full_group_by" necessary for you?

If not, change the sql_mode:

```
SET sql_mode = '';
```

OR

```
SET sql_mode = 'STRICT_ALL_TABLES';
```

Comment: I'm not sure where this line of code needs to go, or if I need to include something for the compiler to understand "SET". I also don't know if it's necessary. I didn't choose that mode, it's the default I guess.

Comment: Just execute this as a single SQL before your query.

Comment: Oh I see, okay I will try that now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you're using `group by`, everything in your `select` clause must EITHER be an aggregate function (like `min`, `max`, `count` etc), OR be in the `group by` clause.

You need to include `Ticker` and `TransDate` in the `group by` clause.

Comment: Right, I kinda figured that out through trial and error, and if I do include all the non-aggregate selections the error goes away - but then the ResutSet is empty.

Comment: That's a whole different question.  Knowing why there appears to be no data in your database table is possibly beyond the scope of Stack Overflow.

Comment: The database shouldn't be empty, as it exists specifically for my class to access and draw data from for this assignment. Does it seem like the query is correct, then? I'll double check that the database has data.

Comment: I suspect that `TradingDays` isn't being set to what you think it is; and then the `having TradingDays >= 150` is removing data that it shouldn't.  But this is just pure speculation about what your data might be; which is why I suggested that it's beyond Stack Overflow to solve this for you.  Anyway, try temporarily removing the `having` clause, just to understand what `TradingDays` is being set to.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your help so far, I really appreciate it. I removed the having clause and the ResultSet is still empty. The data is about stocks, where Tickers are short stock names like AMZN, GOOGL, CTL, LVLT, etc. TransDays are just days where a stock trade occurred, and so they have an associated date and stock prices. (Edit: I keep hitting enter on accident, sorry. New to stackoverflow.) And we're supposed to ignore stocks that had fewer than 150 TradingDays, thus count(TransDatys) must be greater than 149.

Comment: You're correct, it's the 'having' clause that's causing an empty 'ResultSet'.